# Проблемы Gradle билда Unity

Tags: android, unity3d, gradle

Gradle установлен

создана его глобальная

Unity 2018.3.12f1 (64-bit)

Такая же проблема и при экспорте в Android Studio

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в targetSdkVersion 
этот параметр стоял у меня на 23. Насколько я понял все эти элементы доступны при версии 26. 
Может это не совсем точно но мою проблему решило